# Count of indexes of pandas pivot table DF

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have given df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
                         "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar","zz","zz"],
                  "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
                         "one", "one", "two", "two","xy","zz"],
                   "Name":["Peter", "Amy", "Brian", "Amy", "Amy",
                         "Peter", "Brian", "Peter", "Brian","Brian","Brian"],
                  "Year": [2019, 2019, 2019, 2019,
                         2019, 2019, 2020, 2020,
                          2020,2019,2020],
                  "Values": [20, 4, 20, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9,10,5]})
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Values', index=['Name','A', 'B'],
                    columns=['Year'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0, margins=True, 
margins_name="Totals")

print(df_pivot)
```

and after I pivot it in a way I like I have:

```
Year            2019  2020  Totals
Name   A   B                      
Amy    foo one     4     0       4
           two    11     0      11
Brian  bar one     0     8       8
           two     0     9       9
       foo one    20     0      20
       zz  xy     10     0      10
           zz      0     5       5
Peter  bar one     6     0       6
           two     0     9       9
       foo one    20     0      20
Totals            71    31     102
```

now I want to know extract from this DF the complete shape, together with index columns.

The df.shape[0] gives me only number 3, as this is count of "columns with data", but what about first three columns?
Is there a way to count index columns in df?

I know in this example it's three as I defined it, but I want this to be calculated automatically.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.nlevels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.nlevels.html) if need counts levels:

```
print(df_pivot.index.nlevels)
3
print(df_pivot.columns.nlevels)
1
```